# Prioritize transaction with low fee

Tags: json-rpc, regtest, replace-by-fee

**Tx1:**

```
send '{"bcrt1qgz8qhrqyglh7zu3alssydsfa7wk2auucftfnv3": 0.2}' null "unset" 1.1
```

```
{
  "txid": "d040ebe603f80bdf1a92877efeb2b4a27c32766202aeecf3a969b665a0d4c6d8",
  "complete": true
}
```

**Bump fee:**

```
bumpfee d040ebe603f80bdf1a92877efeb2b4a27c32766202aeecf3a969b665a0d4c6d8
```

**Tx2:**

```
{
  "txid": "14f13ad9e757752fce52be3f60a08ff697db646863e68f43e76bd1e70eb4504f",
  "origfee": 0.00000228,
  "fee": 0.00001268,
  "errors": [
  ]
}
```

**Prioritize Tx1:**

```
prioritisetransaction "d040ebe603f80bdf1a92877efeb2b4a27c32766202aeecf3a969b665a0d4c6d8" 0.0 2536
```

```
true
```

**Mine a block:**

```
generatetoaddress 1 "bcrt1qh3v7u6qv46q26srjtjux3cg2g35qlyjf8fqgej"
```

```
[
  "7901e58c61d7e4ed0a07aaef382b5ca6c2f3ec146ed093f443c5e322d4ba3848"
]
```

Why does Tx2 get included in the block even though I tried to prioritize Tx1:

```
getblock "7901e58c61d7e4ed0a07aaef382b5ca6c2f3ec146ed093f443c5e322d4ba3848" 2
```

https://pastebin.com/raw/kYfTsUUG

If this is related to mempool conflicts and the way they are managed in Bitcoin Core, how can I test below scenario using regtest:

1. User broadcasts Tx1 which is relayed and now in the mempool of a node used by mining pools.
2. User replaces it using RBF with Tx2, this transaction is not yet relayed to mempool of nodes used by mining pools.
3. Next block is mined and Tx1 is included in the block

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved. I had to prioritize the transaction before bumping fee, so the correct order of things mentioned in question will be:

1. Tx1
2. Prioritize Tx1
3. Bump fee
4. Tx2
5. Mine a block

Reason: Maybe we can't prioritize a transaction that is already replaced with a new transaction. I think `prioritisetransaction` should have returned some error or at least `false` in this case. However, I noticed it returns `true` for almost any transaction id. I copied a transaction id from testnet explorer and even that `returns` true when I use it with `prioritisetransaction` on regtest.

Comment: Generally you want to prioritize a transaction *before* submitting it, as it might be kicked out of the mempool (or not even make it in) if you don't.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Used this RPC first time. Not sure how it works.